# ToPrimitive VS OrdinaryToPrimitive

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer, coercion

I am reading the Book, YDKJS by Kyle Simpson, topic Coercion. While looking at the [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toprimitive) I found that ToPrimitive calls OrdinaryToPrimitive conditionally. I read in a [blog](https://betterprogramming.pub/advanced-javascript-concepts-you-should-know-460be406711e) that:

> JavaScript view objects with [Symbol.ToPrimitive] method as exotic and the exoticToPrim property become defined

That means if the exoticToPrim property for an object is undefined, OrdinaryToPrimitive is called.

**Example:**

```
 1. var a = 42;    
 2. a + " "; 
 3. String(a);
```

**My Queries** (How Coercion working under the Hood) :

1. Primitive value 'a' will somewhere be boxed to Number object on fly for the sake of concatenation?
2. Hint passed in Line 2 will be default(i.e. Number) but in line 3, it will be string. Hint is passed only for explicit conversion?
3. Will OrdinaryToPrimitive be called during coercion? Since Number.prototype doesn't contain method, Symbol.toPrimitive (Because *Reflect.ownKeys(Array.prototype)* doesn't return Symbol.toPrimitive), hence exoticToPrim would be undefined. And even for other objects (such as Array.prototype doesn't contain this method) so it seems like, as per **spec 7.1.1** 1a and 1b are executed only for **custom** exotic objects (the one which overrides Symbol.Primitive).

Note: I know what Abstract Operations are and that engines define them on their own and that we can't call them explicitly (though override them)

**UPDATED**
Following is an excerpt from his Book:

[image]

He then says:

[image]

Comment: You realize that `a + " "` doesn't do anything right?

Comment: @Pointy What do you mean by doesn't do anything? Can you please elaborate. I think for a + " " it first boxes to Number then calls ValueOf() because of Hint as Number (spec 7.1.1 - 1c) then calls toString to concatenate with " ".

Comment: @Pointy the operation absolute does something in terms of the JS engine. We're just not capturing the result because the result is not relevant to the question, which is about how the type coercion resolves during this statement.

Comment: The statement `a + " "` does not change the value of anything; it is an expression, but it does not affect the environment.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans well that may in fact be what the question is about, but I don't know how I'm supposed to know that because it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: "*JavaScript view objects with [Symbol.ToPrimitive] method as exotic*" - no, that is not [the definition of an "exotic object"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#exotic-object). Naming that variable in the abstract operation `exoticToPrim` is rather misleading, admittedly.

Comment: @Bergi Yes you are right.. An exotic object is any form of object whose property semantics differ in any way from the default semantics.

Answer (score 2):

> Primitive value 'a' will somewhere be boxed to Number object on fly for the sake of concatenation?

No. You missed that the `[Symbol.toPrimitive]` property only applies to **objects**. You can see that the first operation *ToPrimitive* does is to check "*If `input` is an Object*".

So this doesn't apply at all. No boxing happens, no methods are called. The primitive value `42` is immediately returned back from *ToPrimitive*. It is then passed to the [*ToString* operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tostring) since the other operand of `+` is a string.

> Hint is passed only for explicit conversion?

You can easily check the spec for all places where *ToPrimtive* is called. In general, a hint will be passed, the only places I found where none is passed are the `+` operator, the `==`/`!=` operators when comparing an object to a primitive value, and weirdly when calling `new Date` with a single argument (that is not a `Date` object).

> Will `OrdinaryToPrimitive` be called during coercion?

No. Coercion using the [`String()` function](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string-constructor-string-value) directly calls (except for symbols) the [*ToString* operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tostring) which does, again, not use *ToPrimitive* (or *OrdinaryToPrimitive*) on non-objects. Instead, for numbers it directly dispatches to the [number-to-string operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring).

Comment: Please check UPDATED part. In his Book Kyle claims that valueOf is called before toString. I think 'a' is converted to Object at runtime (How could it call the method on primitive type?) with Hint being passed as Number, which calls valueOf and then toString to concatenate. Otherwise, how would it be possible to call valueOf before toString

Comment: The book is just wrong on that part. There is no object, so there is no method call. All this only applies when `a` is not a primitive.

Comment: ok if you say no method is called, then how would 'a' which is number primitive gets converted to string (without any method).

Comment: `+` and `String` directly use *ToString* which uses *Number::toString*. (See the links in the last paragraph of my answer)